# Expression for Hamiltonian vector field!

Tags: classical-mechanics, symplectic-geometry, vector-fields

How does one prove that the Hamiltonian vector field has the following expression, what is the reasoning?
\begin{equation}
X_H=\sum ^n_{i=1}\frac{\partial H}{\partial q_i}\frac{\partial }{\partial p_i}+\sum ^n_{i=1}\frac{\partial H}{\partial p_i}\frac{\partial }{\partial q_i}
\end{equation}
In pretty much every text I read it is "obvious" or "implied" it takes that form if we use Cartan's formula and the Lie derivative. I am familiar with both symplectic geometry and the basics of differential geometry. I am sorry if it is either obvious or basic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $H$ be the Hamiltonian.  By definition, $X_H$ is the unique vector field which satisfies
$$\omega(X_H, Y) = dH(Y)$$
for all vector fields $Y$.  Equivalently, $\iota_{X_H}\omega = dH$.

By the uniqueness of $X_H$, it suffices to check that the formula you quoted does indeed satisfy $\omega(X_H, Y) = dH(Y)$ for all vector fields $Y$.  I leave this for you to check; once you check this, you're done, that's it.

---

However, if you want to see how to actually *derive* the formula, here's how to do that.  In Darboux coordinates, we can write
$$X_H =  \sum a^i \frac{\partial}{\partial p_i} + \sum b_i \frac{\partial}{\partial q_i}$$
for some functions $a_i$ and $b_i$.

On the one hand,
$$dH = \sum \left( \frac{\partial H}{\partial p_i}\,dp_i + \frac{\partial H}{\partial q_i}\,dq_i\right).$$
On the other hand,
$$\iota_{X_H}\omega = \left( \sum a^i \frac{\partial}{\partial p_i} + \sum b_i \frac{\partial}{\partial q_i} \right) \,\lrcorner\,\left( \sum dp_i \wedge dq_i \right) = \sum (a^i\,dq_i - b^i\,dp_i).$$
Equating $dH = \iota_{X_H}\omega$ gives that
\begin{align}
a^i & = \frac{\partial H}{\partial q_i} \\
b^i & = -\frac{\partial H}{\partial p_i},
\end{align}
as claimed.

Comment: Brilliant, Thank you !