# Explicit derivation of the interior product between the Hamiltonian Vector Field and the symplectic two-form

Tags: vector-fields, symplectic-geometry, hamilton-jacobi-equation

I am trying to understand Example 5.12 of the book *Geometry, Topology and Physics* by Nakahara. In particular, consider the two-form $\omega=dp_{\mu} \wedge dq^{\mu}$ (1) and the Hamiltonian vector field
 $X_f=\frac{\partial f}{\partial p_{\mu}}\frac{\partial }{\partial q^{\mu}}-\frac{\partial f}{\partial q^{\mu}}\frac{\partial }{\partial p_{\mu}}$ (2)

In the book it says that "it is easy to verify" that:

$i_{X_f} \omega = -\frac{\partial f}{\partial p_{\mu}}dp^{\mu}-\frac{\partial f}{\partial q^{\mu}} dq^{\mu}=-df$  (3).

But I am a bit confused about how to explicitly verify (3), and I think part of my confusion is that I am not sure what the components of $X_f$ are.  For example, in the case $X=y\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-x\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$, I know that $X^{\mu=1}=y$ and $X^{\mu=2}=-x$. However, in the case at hand it seems that one component is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial p_{\mu}}$ and $-\frac{\partial f}{\partial q^{\mu}}$ seems to be the other component. Is that right?  If so, then  the index $\mu$ in $X_{f}$ does not seem to be indicating the components of the field. (As a side-note question: why $dp$ has $\mu$ as a lower index and $dq$ has it as an upper index? In all the other examples in that chapter, we always had two-forms written as $dx^{\mu_1} \wedge dx^{\mu_2}$ with both indices up.)

Now, as it is explained in the book (Eq. 5.79), in general, for an r-form $\omega$,

$i_{X}\omega=1/r! \sum_{s=1}^r X^{\mu_s}\omega_{\mu_1...\mu_{s}...\mu_r}(-1)^{s-1}dx^{\mu_1}\wedge...\wedge \hat{dx^{\mu_s}}\wedge...\wedge dx^{\mu_r} $ (4),

where the hat over $dx^{\mu_s}$ indicates that this element is omitted. In the case at hand, $r=2$, and so we only have two terms for the sum in (4). But I cannot use this formula precisely because I am confused about the meaning of $X^{\mu_s}$ for the vector field in question. So, in summary: **can someone please show me as explicit as possible how to verify (3) by using the general formula (4) in the case of the vector field (2)?**   (I already read this question [Expression for Hamiltonian vector field!](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1116112/expression-for-hamiltonian-vector-field) but it did not help me much because at the moment of computing the inner product they were not as explicit as I needed to understand).  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

In classical mechanics, the first and simplest context in which the Hamilton equations appear is on the cotangent manifold $T^*Q$ of the configuration space $Q$ of a system. In this context, coordinates $(q^1, \dots, q^n)$ on (an open set $U$ of) $Q$ induce special coordinates on (the corresponding open set $T^*U$ of) $T^*Q$, for instance $(x^1, \dots, x^{2n}) = (q^1, \dots, q^n, p_1, \dots, p_n)$, or alternatively $(y^1, \dots, y^{2n}) = (q^1, p_1, \dots, q^n, p_n)$, or many other alternatives. Some choice of convention is at play here. (I postponed the explanation of the strange index position on the $p$'s to the end of this answer.)

If we were to choose the first convention, we then have $x^{\nu} = q^{\mu}$ if $\nu = \mu \le n$ and $x^{\nu} = p_{\mu}$ if $\nu = \mu + n > n$. We write $X_f = (X_f)^{\nu} \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\nu}}$ and we aim to show that $(X_f)^{\nu} = \partial f/\partial p_{\mu}$ when $\nu \le n$ and  $(X_f)^{\nu} = - \partial f/\partial q^{\mu}$ when $\nu > n$. The symplectic 2-form is $\omega = \sum_{\mu=1}^n dp_{\mu} \wedge dq^{\mu}$ (the overall sign is a convention which I were able to deduce from what you wrote in your question; see what follows), and we compute

$$ \begin{align}
\sum_{\mu=1}^n \left[ - \frac{\partial f}{\partial q^{\mu}} dq^{\mu}  - \frac{\partial f}{\partial p^{\mu}} dp_{\mu} \right] &= - df \\
&= i_{X_f} \omega = \sum_{\mu=1}^n [(i_{X_f} dp_{\mu}) \wedge dq^{\mu} - dp_{\mu} \wedge (i_{X_f}dq^{\mu})  ] \\
&= \sum_{\mu=1}^n [ (i_{X_f} dx^{\mu+n}) \wedge dq^{\mu} - dp_{\mu} \wedge (i_{X_f} dx^{\mu})] \\
&= \sum_{\mu=1}^n [(X_f)^{\mu+n}  dq^{\mu} - dp_{\mu}  (X_f)^{\mu}]
\end{align}$$

so that $(X_f)^{\mu+n} = - \partial f/\partial q^{\mu}$ and $(X_f)^{\mu} = \partial f/\partial p_{\mu}$, as claimed. The notation used in this calculation is closer to what is common to differential geometers; physicists are more used to the abstract index notation, where $\omega = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{\nu, \lambda=1}^{2n} \omega_{\nu \lambda} dx^{\nu} \wedge dx^{\lambda}$ with $\omega_{\nu \lambda} =   \delta_{n, \nu - \lambda} - \delta_{n, \lambda - \nu}$ and one would use the formula you wrote to compute the contraction $i_{X_f}\omega$. It is however exactly the same calculation as above.

Regarding the reason why the coordinate index is lowered on the $p$'s, one could (and perhaps, pedantically, should) write coordinates on $T^*Q$ with upper indices, as we did for the $x$'s or the $y$'s above. But the fact is that a point $P \in T^*Q$ is given by the data of a configuration $q \in Q$ and of a covector $p \in T^*_q Q$. One can write the covector $p$ in the coordinates $q^{\mu}$ as $p = p_{\mu}dq^{\mu}$, which is compatible with the abstract index notation applied on $Q$. The scalars $p_{\mu}$'s serve themselves as coordinates on $T^*_q Q$. So if we want our notation for the induced coordinates on $T^*Q$ to be explicit about the origin of these induced coordinates, we have to stick with the $p_{\mu}$'s with their lower index, against what would prescribe the usual index notation for coordinates on a manifold.

On general symplectic manifolds, because of the existence of Darboux coordinates (also called 'canonical coordinates') which allow to locally think of the symplectic manifold as part of a cotangent bundle, we push this abuse of notation somewhat further by writing Darboux coordinates in the form $(q^{\mu}, p_{\mu})$. (This abuse of notation implicitly conveys the idea of the local equivalence of all symplectic manifolds of the same dimension.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it clarifies things a lot!!